# Dropdown menu masonry (JS) not working when preset status is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I hope someone has a solution for me here :-)
What I'd like to achieve is a menu-dropdown with a masonry layout. I found a great script, which is working really well! But .. it's not working when I hide the dropdown container on forehand. I guess this has something to do with the script not capable of calculate values when the container is hidden.

Please check this fiddle to make it more clear:

[jsfiddle masonry dropdown example](https://jsfiddle.net/hielkio/0ox69dgh/22/)

Just toggle between these two lines:

```
<div class="p-4" id="main-menu">
<div class="p-4 hidden" id="main-menu">
```

And you will see what's going wrong...

Here's a screenshot of the situation where the container is visible on forehand:
[image]

And here when it's hidden:
[image]

I really hope someone could provide me with a workaround, because my mind is almost exploding :-D LoL!

Thank you very much in advance for thinking with me!

Answer (score 1):

By setting the `main-menu` visibility to hidden during the library initialization it seems to work.

> Note i added to position: absolute in case because `visibility: hidden`
> doesn't change the layout

https://jsfiddle.net/m5djy03q/2/

Comment: Great approach! But it's not completely fixed unfortunately :-(

check: https://i.imgur.com/up0nxWq.png

When I resize the window, the layout get fixed though

Comment: Removing `position: absolute` solves the problem but you may have layout problems afterwards.

Comment: Wow! At first glance it looks very promising!
What layout problems would you expect, because I can't find any reason for it. I mark your answer as solution Namysh! Great job and many, many thanks!

Comment: This may seem specific but if there are elements where the menu will appear, without absolute the menu will follow the layout and go up or down according to the HTML order whereas with absolute position, the menu will always be in front of all elements (depending on how masonry is working internally)

Comment: Unfortunately there are other problems under the hood with this solution. My Pagespeed Insights score drops from 98 to 77 due to huge layout shifting.